# The word "ornamental" : is it an opinion adjective, a purpose adjective, or part of a compound noun here?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, compound-words, adjective-position

Upon reviewing my notes on the order of adjectives, I saw that "ornamental" was listed as an opinion adjective. However, wouldn't ornamental be a "purpose" or "type" adjective? I am using the order of adjectives as listed [in the Cambridge Dictionary.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) I have three phrases here:

1. the old ornamental vase
2. the ornamental iron work
3. ornamental gilt bronze frames

For example, in #1 I don't think it's right to my ear to say the "ornamental old vase". It sounds better to say the "old ornamental vase". I also wonder if in this situation "ornamental vase" is just one unit/compound noun, which is why it doesn't feel right to say "ornamental old vase".

In #2 I have material = iron, and I'm not sure what category ornamental would be.

For #3, same as #2. What category would ornamental be?

Comment: #4 The order emphasises different things. An _old ornamental vase_ and an _ornamental old vase_ aren't necessarily the same thing. The former sounds like _ornamental_ is an intrinsic property of the vase whereas the latter doesn't.

Comment: Yes I see your point. Now they both sound right the more I think of it that way.

Comment: 'Ornamental' perhaps defaults now in sense to 'decorative _but not in the least bit useful_'; it is this sense that must be quite open to opinion (though one could say that even with the purely 'decorative' sense, one man's 'ornamental' is another man's 'X!*m#!$').  This shows that the compartmentalising of adjectives (and even of their senses) into neat semantic sets is a pipe-dream. // There have been other posts on ELU illustrating that the 'Royal Order of Adjectives' itself, even if one _can_ compartmentalise most of them, is hardly a rule that always applies.